# Is there a way to derive a function inverse from the function?

Tags: functions, special-functions, inverse-function

I was looking at the [logit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit), $\operatorname{logit}(p)=\log\dfrac{p}{1-p}$, and I just realized that the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), $S(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$, was its inverse function.

I could not come up with a way to get to the inverse from the original function, and it got me thinking if there was a way to derive a function inverse from the function itself?

Comment: Solve $\ln(x/1-x)=y$, i.e., $x=e^y-xe^y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y=\log\frac{x}{1-x}=\log\frac1{1-\dfrac1x}$$

$$e^y=\frac1{1-\dfrac1x}$$

$$e^{-y}=1-\dfrac1x$$

$$1-e^{-y}=\dfrac1x$$

$$\frac1{1-e^{-y}}=x$$

The trick I used is to isolate a single instance of the variable and see the function as a composition of elementary functions with known inverses.

Comment: can you explain how you got $\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{x}}$ in the first step? I can't quite follow why this is true